# Dice probability help

Tags: probability, game-theory, dice

I have just started a game with my wife. We rolled $2$ six sided dice twice in this order:

1. She rolled $\{5,6\}$.
2. Then i rolled $\{5,6\}$ as well.
3. Then she rolled $\{2,5\}$.
4. Then i rolled $\{2,5\}$ as well.

What were the odds of me getting the same numbers twice?

Comment: Is 2 D6 short for 2 six sided dice?

Comment: Yes, i mean 2 six sided dice.

Comment: were the dice fair ?

Comment: Does order matter?  That is, would you have said that $(5,2)$ was the same roll as $(2,5)$?

Comment: Dice were fair.

Comment: Order doesn't matter : (5-2) equals (2-5) here.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is to determine the probability of a single match.  Since "match" disregards order, that takes a computation.  Rolls $(a,b)$ with $a\neq b$ have two matches, but rolls $(a,a)$ have only one.  Thus there are two ways to get a match:

Either the first player throws a double and then the second throws the same double, $\frac 16\times \frac 1{36}$.  Or the first player throws a non-double and then the second throws a match up to order, probability $\frac 56\times \frac 2{36}$

Thus the probability of a single match is $$\frac 16\times \frac 1{36}+\frac 56\times \frac 2{36}=\frac {11}{216}\approx .051$$

To do it twice we must square, so the final answer is $$\left(\frac {11}{216}\right)^2=\frac {121}{46656}\approx .0026$$

Comment: except with the order not mattering there's only 21 possibilities:

(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,5),(5,6),and (6,6)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  Not following.  If you throw a $(2,5)$ then there are two things I can throw to match you.  Thus the probability of my matching you is $\frac 2{36}$, yes?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  I am working with all the rolls, so each roll is equi-probable.  Therefore I need to say that there are two rolls which match the non-double.

Comment: almost all of them are even in the 21 cases the only ones that aren't are when a=b.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  So what?  With problems like these you have two ways to proceed.  Either you can work with equi-probable rolls (as I did) in which case you can have multiple matches or you can work with the un-ordered rolls in which case there is only one way to match but the rolls are not equi-probable.  Personal choice, but I always prefer to work with equi-probable events when possible.

Comment: sorry for being an idiot then. though in the 21 case one you get rough odds of 0.00226... in the case of any one of the rolls with just $({1\over21})^2={1\over441}$ all in one step.